# How to create a firebase project with same structure as an existing one?

Tags: firebase

I'm working on a product which uses Firebase as its backend. Since firebase exposes the API keys to the user so that could be a security issue. So, after doing some research I've set the database security rules along with API keys restrictions.

But, now I'm unable to use it in local development as well. I was thinking of creating another firebase project and use that as a testing environment and use the existing one as production.

Since the existing project has a lot of data and users. I want everything similar in the new firebase project as well. But I'm unable to find an efficient way to do so. Can anyone please suggest what would be the best option here? Should I create a new testing environment or is there a way to allow me to use the keys locally without it causing a security concern?

Any help would be great. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific command to replicate one project to another, but you can build the necessary functionality yourself with each product's APIs.

For porting users between projects you can use:

1. The Firebase CLI, which has [`auth:import` and `auth:export`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth) commands.
2. The Firebase Admin SDK, which has commands to [list all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) and [import a list of users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users).

For transferring data between the projects, you can use the API of the relevant database to read/write the data.

Comment: I'm using the [Import/Export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) feature to transfer data between cloud firestore of two projects. I was able to export the data into a bucket. But I'm having issues in importing data as both the databases have to be in a different multi-region location(us and eur) so I'm not sure whether the transfer will work and I can't even test it since selecting a location for cloud firestore is an immutable selection. What would be the best option here?

Comment: As far as I know the export can be imported into another region. But as said: I'd probably use the regular API to accomplish the data transfer between the two environments.